# ASP.NET using Entity Framework display data to drop down list with distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Please I need to implement distinct in `a.CompanyName` but it doesn't work. What do I need to do ?

```
try
{
    var listCompany = company.CompanyList();

    companyList1.DataSource = listCompany.Select(a => new { a.CompanyName, a.CompanyId }).Distinct();
    companyList1.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
    companyList1.DataValueField = "CompanyId";
    companyList1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

> > Groups the elements of a sequence.

```
companyList1.DataSource = listCompany
             .GroupBy(x => x.CompanyName)
             .Select(a => new 
                   { CompanyName = a.First().CompanyName, CompanyId = a.First().CompanyId });
```

Above query will group your result by company name and then will select `CompanyName` and `CompanyId` of first record

[Try out online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1urbn)